# Why I am getting Value error on Linear Regression method fit()

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression

I have executed the code below and encountered an error at the line `regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
y= dataset.iloc[:,-1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size = .2,random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

plt.scatter(X_train,y_train, color ='red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Salary vs Experience (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()


plt.scatter(X_test,y_test, color ='red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Salary vs Experience (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

**The error I am getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ayushsharma/PycharmProjects/Machine_Learning/simple_linear_regression.py", line 14, in <module>
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/Users/ayushsharma/env/bin/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ayushsharma/env/bin/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 678, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/Users/ayushsharma/env/bin/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 621, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/Users/ayushsharma/env/bin/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1147, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/Users/ayushsharma/env/bin/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 940, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[112635.  55794.  83088. 101302.  56642.  66029.  64445.  61111. 113812.
  91738.  46205. 121872.  60150.  39891.  81363.  93940.  57189.  54445.
 105582.  43525.  39343.  98273.  67938.  56957.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Process finished with exit code 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL6EM.png)
```

**My Dataset:**

```
YearsExperience,Salary
1.1,39343.00
1.3,46205.00
1.5,37731.00
2.0,43525.00
2.2,39891.00
2.9,56642.00
3.0,60150.00
3.2,54445.00
3.2,64445.00
3.7,57189.00
3.9,63218.00
4.0,55794.00
4.0,56957.00
4.1,57081.00
4.5,61111.00
4.9,67938.00
5.1,66029.00
5.3,83088.00
5.9,81363.00
6.0,93940.00
6.8,91738.00
7.1,98273.00
7.9,101302.00
8.2,113812.00
8.7,109431.00
9.0,105582.00
9.5,116969.00
9.6,112635.00
10.3,122391.00
10.5,121872.00
```

My goal when executing this code is to create a Linear Regression model. Additionally, I aim to generate visual plots representing both the training and test set results. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Just like the error says, the fit method expects a 2D array for both `x` and `y` so just reshape the data as the error message advises. I'd also have to point out that both your `x` and `y` are exactly the same